# C++ , class private variables

Tags: c++

Considering the following class :

```
class account   
{

    char name[30];
    char  fam[30];
    int fr_count;
    bool fl_dost;
    account *friends[10];
public: 

    account();
    account(char *n, char* f);
    int add_fr(account *fr);
}


int main()
{

    account ob1("Ivan", "Petrov"), ob2("Gosho","Gosho"), ob3("fa","za"), ob4("Gosho","Gosho");
    ob1.add_fr(&ob2);
    ob1.add_fr(&ob3);
    ob1.add_fr(&ob4);

    getchar();
    return 0;

}
```

And the method :

```
int account::add_fr(account *fr)

{   

    int flag = 0;
    if (fr_count >= 100) 
    {
        cout << "Full" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < fr_count; i++)
    {
        if (!strcmp(friends[i]->name, fr->name) && !strcmp(friends[i]->fam, fr->fam))
        {
            flag = 1;
        }
    }

    if (flag)
    {
        cout << "Exist" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    friends[fr_count] = fr;
    fr_count++;

    return 1;
}
```

My questions is : Why i am able to access the private members `friends[i]->name` and `friends[i]->fam`   in the method `add::fr(account *fr)`?

Comment: Because the method is in the class and thus has access to all of it's members?

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you didn't know member functions can access private members, how did you want to use those private members?

Answer (score 4):

Let's visit cppreference to review what `private` does.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access

> A private member of a class can only be accessed by the members and friends of that class, **regardless of whether the members are on the same or different instances**

You are able to access private members of `account` because you are doing it from a member function of `account`.

Answer (score 0):

It can access because the method is in the class and thus has access to all of it's members. Private/protected/public apply to methods outside of the class.